# Переклад українською мовою словосполучення «бегущая строка»

Tags: переклад

Нещодавно спробувала перекласти з російської мови українською вираз **«бегущая строка»**. 
По-перше, скористалась словником-перекладачем онлайн Google   . Він видав мені переклад **«біжучий рядок»**. Такий переклад мені не сподобався і я звернулась до російсько-українського словника. Получила ще один переклад **«текст із прокруткою»**.

Розуміючи, що це стійке словосполучення, складне для перекладу, прочитала [статтю про культуру мовлення](http://l-ponomar.com/kultura-movy-yak-pravylno-skazaty-ukrayinskoyu-deyaki-movni-klishe/#ixzz59VzHOTkp). Автор статті рекомендує використовувати вираз **рухомий рядок**. Наводить приклад вживання його у реченні:

> Під час перегляду випуску новин я не маю звички читати **рухомий рядок**: він відволікає мене від сприйняття основної інформації.

Допоможіть, любі друзі, вибрати правильний варіант.

Comment: чому ми перекладаємо з російської? це питання не до вас. Англійською - *crawl*. Може й нам назвати *повзунка*, бо *стрічка, що повзе*.

Comment: @Yola, цікаво було б побачити статистику швидкостей таких рядків у новнах різних країн/мов/агентств — може, воно справді там біжить (швидко), а там повзе (повільно)? До речі, якщо кому потрібно, ось англійська стаття: [News ticker (crawler, crawl or slide)](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_ticker), я чомусь не відразу знайшов.

Answer (score 9):

В відео уроках української мови телепрограми **[Сніданок 1+1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pC3Ro4gib24)** Олександр Авраменко радить вживати ***"рухомий рядок"***

[Уроки державної мови](http://mova.kreschatic.kiev.ua/14.php)

> З погляду лексичних і словотвірних норм дієприкметник біжучий
>   сприймається як застарілий. Сучасна літературна мова послуговується,
>   зокрема і в термінологічному слововжитку, прикметниками рухомий,
>   рухливий, наприклад: "Якщо в лавах мало кремнезему, то вони дуже
>   рідкі, рухливі, текучі" (з журналу); "У давнину люди виявили на небі
>   сім рухомих небесних тіл, бачили семибарвну райдугу" (з журналу).
>   Отже, на електронних рекламах бачимо й читаємо ***рухомий рядок.***